# Using django-allauth for authorized Twitter API actions

Tags: python, django, api, twitter, django-allauth

I'm trying to build an app that interacts with the Twitter API (posting statuses, toggling settings, etc.). I've found django-allauth to simplify log-in, etc., and I like what it does.

The problem is that allauth seems to only authenticate the user; it doesn't appear to authorize my app to work on a users behalf. Can anyone point me to a resource where I can see how to tap into the allauth data to create an authorization? (if that even exists) Thanks!

Comment: have you considered using tweepy?

Comment: I have considered using tweepy. tweepy is great for most things, but there's a few features of the Twitter API that isn't included in tweepy, such as the ability to create and destroy mutes. Or at least it's not obvious from the docs I read. I'm instead using the TwitterAPI library. Similar functionality, but more robust as far as I can tell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you need to understand more about the Twitter APIs. Check the developer section of twitter and see available apis for pulling the data using access token. Once you've understanding on that, then what you need to do is just fetch the authenticated user access token like this (I'vent tested this but I hope this will work.)

```
social = user.social_auth.get(provider='twitter')
access_token = social.extra_data['access_token']['token']
```

Now you have the access_token on authenticated user so you can use any python library like requests, urllib2 or even there might be wrappers written on top of those and can pull the data. Hope this helps you. :)

Comment: Thanks! You were right that it was a more basic thing I didn't understand. It's not the Twitter API I didn't quite understand, but forgetting to import the allauth models.

Comment: Please mark answer accepted in case you feel someone get struck at similar issue and can find it useful.. Happy Coding.. cheers. :)